# Display an OLE Object from a table in a word doc [VBA]

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

So I need to **display a picture** in a **word doc** at a **bookmark**. This picture is stored in a **MS Access Database** as an **OLE Object**.

I know how to write at a bookmark

```
WordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("myBookmark").Range.Text = value
```

And for the moment, here what i've done:

```
'xNum is the product number
Dim s As OLEObjects
Dim x As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
xSQL = "SELECT stuff FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.par = table2.par WHERE NumProduct=" & xNum
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(xSQL)
s = rs!stuff
x = 1
Do While Not rs.EOF
       If x = 1 Then
            '{Command to insert an OLE at a word's bookmark}
       ElseIf x = 2 Then
       ...
       End If
   rs.MoveNext
   x = x + 1
Loop
rs.Close
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

*P.S: I'm a newbie on vba/Ms Access, but I made some C# (which looks a bit like vba)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## So I finally came up with a solution!

The idea is to put each picture (OLE Object) in an Image frame in an Access Form, and then focus this object (Image frame) in order to proceed a copy and paste in our word doc, at the specific range we just set before. By the way, this Image frame must be enabled, unlocked and visible.

#### Cordially, the developer who answers his self!